# Position of the prefix in a separable-prefix verb in a sentence?

Tags: grammar-identification

> – Hör auf mich zu schlagen
>   – Er sieht aus wie einer

Is saying

> Hör mich zu schlagen auf.
>   Er sieht wie einer aus.

correct?
As far as I know, aren't the separable prefix supposed to go to the very end of the clause?

Answer (score 2):

You ommited a comma therefore you could not see it's actually two clauses:

> Hör auf **,** mich zu schlagen.

The alternative

> Hör mich zu schlagen auf.

is gramatically correct but sounds incredibly clumsy. However, *zu+Infinitiv* is only second choice. German speakers love nouns!

> Hör mit dem Schlagen auf.

You had to omit the *mich* but if this is understandable from context it's not required anyway.

---

You next sentence seems incomplete. A relative clause has to follow:

> Er sieht aus wie einer **, der …**
>
> Er sieht wie einer aus **, der …**

These are both common. The first is sort of a fixed phrase, so we condone the lack of proper grammar.

Comment: In the first sentence it was copied from a book and there was no comma but I saw other sentences with the same structure that had a comma separating the clauses.
But the book also said that the new spelling reform doesn't make the comma mandatory (which is bad in my opinion)

But in the second sentence. I simply wanted to say "He looks like one" with no following clauses.

Isn't "Er sieht aus wie einer" correct? According to google translate (not necessarily the best source of course) it seems to be fine though

Comment: If that "Er sieht aus wie einer" was a complete sentence, are adding "aus" right after the main verb and to the end of the sentence (Er sieht wie einer aus) BOTH correct?

Comment: The comma rules of that spelling reform are pointless and make it actually harder to understand sentence structure. They had been revised again and now you are "encouraged" to use that comma. –A committee decided on these new rules. 'nuff said.– English *"He looks like one."* should be translated as *So sieht er jedenfalls/zumindest aus.* It's a fixed phrase, the "at least" should not be ommited in German.

Comment: No, not correct. Not having the relative clause shrieks "I'm English! I'm English!"

Comment: According to my *Sprachgefühl* *Hör mich zu schlagen auf* is ungrammatical. I am not completely sure about the reason, but it seems that the infinitive construction with *zu* has to be placed outside the sentence bracket.

Comment: Then it is clear to me why "Auf" would be followed right after "Hör" since "mich zu schlagen" seems to be the relative clause here hence the need to be separated bz the comma. 

But I am not clear as to how "Er sieht wie einer aus" (He looks like one) is incorrect.
There doesn't seem to be any separate clauses here so shouldn't "aus" go to the very end?

Comment: *Er sieht wie einer aus.* is gramatically correct. *Er sieht aus wie einer.* is gramatically incorrect but common. They both need a following relative clause for stylistic reasons. Omitting it makes it sound as a literal translation from English. The common German phrase for your English phrase is ***So** sieht er **auch/jedenfalls/zumindest** aus.*

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the rule is more like, you should put the preposition at the end of the *clause,* rather than at the end of the sentence.

The "sentence" "Hör auf mich zu schlagen." actually has two clauses, "Hor auf." an "mich zu schlagen."

You can put the auf at the end of the whole sentence, but that is awkward because it breaks up the train of thought (even though German does that all the time with verbs). It's easier to use auf to complete the first clause, so that "Hor auf" and "mich zu schlagen" are two separate thoughts.

In "Er sieht wie einer aus," that is a whole clause (not two), so you should put the aus at the end. Yes, some native speakers prefer to break up the clause. "Er sieht aus wie einer," by putting "aus" in the middle. as if it were two clauses, but that is not "standard" usage.

Comment: So is adding the separable-prefix RIGHT after the conjugated verb correct but just uncommon?

Comment: @user268569: It's the other way around. That is, it is quite common, but not always correct. It was done in both instances you cited, but correct in only one out of two.

Comment: I see, thanks again. are you aware of any instance where any other word can come after the separable prefix and also be correct?

Comment: @user268569: Not off the top of my head.